# Trying to port GCC specific asm goto to Clang

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, clang

I've been trying to turn a bit of GNU extensions in to actual standard C so it'll run on clang, knowing standard C and not GNU extensions, I'm at a bit of a loss.

```
    __asm__ (goto("1:"
            STATIC_KEY_INITIAL_NOP
            ".pushsection __jump_table,  \"aw\" \n\t"
            _ASM_ALIGN "\n\t"
            _ASM_PTR "1b, %l[l_yes], %c0 \n\t"
            ".popsection \n\t"
            : :  "i" (key) : : l_yes););
```

I've tried to turn this in to actual asm, but have yet to be successful.

If you're curious, this is part of a kernel I've just about got to build on clang, besides that one section.

Comment: +1 for managing to produce such a thing, although I don't understand it and should probably add a -1 for lack of comments.

Comment: Don't blame me for this mess, it's part of the Linux kernel.

Comment: Oh. I have retagged it. By the way, this is not the domain of standard C.

Comment: Search for the function containing this block of assembly, and you will quickly find out messages (like [this one](http://lwn.net/Articles/429447/)) from the KML indicating the people responsible for this piece of code. Fire an email at them. Also, [read this](http://lwn.net/Articles/436041/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be having a problem compiling [arch/x86/include/asm/jump_label.h](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/jump_label.h). The entire code-snippet is to enable support for "jump label patching". A new feature quite useful to allow debugging(print logs etc.) with have near-zero overhead when debugging is disabled.

The implementation you encounter [depends on gcc(v4.5) which adds a new `asm goto` statement](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2009-07/msg01556.html) that allows branching to a label.

> It appears that [Clang/LLVM < 9.0.0 does NOT support **`asm goto`**](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9295).

As a quick fix to get your Linux kernel compiling properly, you can disable `CONFIG_JUMP_LABEL` in your kernel configuration. This config option is used to disable the optimisation when the compiler does NOT support `asm goto` properly.

---

**Update**: Initial support for `asm goto` was [added to Clang in v9.0.0](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/1634b4bc934d67cb5fa356a925ba8efca2259f12).

> Initial support for `asm goto` statements (a GNU C extension) has been
>     added for control flow from inline assembly to labels. The main consumers of
>     this construct are the Linux kernel (CONFIG_JUMP_LABEL=y) and glib. There are
>     still a few unsupported corner cases in Clang's integrated assembler and
>     IfConverter. Please file bugs for any issues you run into.

Comment: While it won't help me directly fix the code, the fact that I can disable it entirely didn't even cross my mind. This is a pretty valid solution, thanks!

Comment: Asm goto support was merged into LLVM! https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=LLVM-Asm-Goto-Merged :)