# Issue of "Compiler lacks asm-goto support" with CentOS8+gcc 8.3.1

Tags: gcc, makefile, centos8

I have installed CentOS 8.2.2004 minimal onto my PC, using a USB stick.
This PC which has no Internet connection, only has a TP-LINK TL-WN725N USB WiFi dongle , so I have to install linux driver for it. I went to TP-LINK website and downloaded the linux driver(https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201802/20180227/TL-WN725N_V3_Linux.zip) wants to compile/build/install it so make my PC can connect to Internet by this Wifi dongle.  However, i met below compiler error:

****arch/x86/Makefile:184: *** Compiler lacks asm-goto support.. Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:1367: modules] Error 2****

Original CentOS 8.2.2004 minimal has no gcc/make/kernel dev installed, so I have to install them separately by rpm, below are what I have installed:

## rpm -qa|grep kernel

kernel-tools-libs-4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64

kernel-modules-4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64

kernel-tools-4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64

kernel-4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64

kernel-core-4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64

kernel-devel-4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64

## rpm -qa|grep gcc

gcc-8.3.1-5.el8.0.2.x86_64

gcc-toolset-9-runtime-9.0-4.el8.x86_64

libgcc-8.3.1-5.el8.0.2.x86_64

gcc-c++-8.3.1-5.el8.0.2.x86_64

## rpm -qa|grep make

cmake-3.11.4-7.el8.x86_64

automake-1.16.1-6.el8.noarch

make-4.2.1-10.el8.x86_64

## as --version

GNU assembler version 2.30-73.el8
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `x86_64-redhat-linux'.

## uname -r

4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64

## cat /proc/version

Linux vrsion 4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64(mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org)(gcc version 8.3.1 20191121(Red Hat 8.3.1-5)(GCC))#1 SMP Fri May 8 10:59:10 UTC 2020

What's wrong?

Hoping someone can help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Some reports on "stale Makefile caches" being the issue, might want to check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456318

Comment: Thanks, also read it, tried with "make clean", does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the elfutils-libelf-devel package.

This package is from the baseos but isn't always needed. You will likely need it for out of tree kernel modules compilation.